# Get US price for a product

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am currently scraping information from websites, it's not allowed but this is just for testing purposes. Is there a way for me to be able to get the US price for this site below:

http://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-mc/Aidan-Mattox-Strapless-Lace-Mermaid-Gown-Black/prod168090058/p.prod

When I scrape for the price using XPATH, it would return in EUR because the URL points to Monaco, is there a way for me to force it to go to the US location and get the US price?

Also, if I scrape the US site equivalent, I get the price to my country's currency! Why is that? I have tried different Cookie settings but to no avail.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATED**

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1"; //"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))";
webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
webRequest.Pipelined = true; 
webRequest.KeepAlive = true; 
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000000;

CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("TLTUID", "8CEA4FE6032D10034476D9238143ECBE"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("AGA", "4700001:4700002~6300001:6500002~6300002:6500003~6300003:6500005~6100006:6300012~5400001:5400001~6100005:6300010~5400002:5400004"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("ABTEST_COOKIE", "27272067069"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("ABTEST_COOKIE_CONFIRM", "29261c31634866ee227a8925b2352cb1"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("DYN_USER_ID", "9256667771"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("DYN_USER_CONFIRM", "ea1d2018d8c1d09299461b302b463ef7"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("WID", "8923541876"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("s_pers", "%20s_v17%3DNot%2520Assigned%7C1441079500079%3B%20s_v18%3DNot%2520Assigned%7C1441079500079%3B%20s_v20%3D0%7C1441079500079%3B%20s_v19%3D9256667771%7C1441079500079%3B%20s_fid%3D48B74ECD3257A317-39E69F2E9186682C%7C1472701900923%3B%20s_nr%3D1409543500955-Repeat%7C1441079500955%3B%20gpv%3DChange%2520Shipping%2520Country%7C1409545300977%3B"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("s_vi", "[CS]v1|29DB119A85012607-4000160360002C25[CE]"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("_br_mzv", "eyIxIjo3LCIyIjoxNDA0NDQ1NTAxMDgwLCIzIjoxNDA5NTQxOTE3MTg5LCI0IjoiaHR0cDovL3d3dy5uZWltYW5tYXJjdXMuY29tLyIsIjUiOiIifQ"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("_br_uid_2", "uid%3D5027964663387%3Av%3D11.5%3Ats%3D1404445501090%3Ahc%3D28"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("__cmbU", "ABJeb196hmGU2LSmkjXEtIaC4Mi4ziQnJuj6d5pFZSVCiyzg1rLfVOZ8X5WlzXyGCXJY-VijDT8JTH6ZzGto0QAbGuFJriL0Qg"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("NMCS", "3ugYcZdPOmDj7QQ6w2UCrRa0iFJaIb_vPPZApLltp7OUOov6zBSy8mA"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("__cmbDomTm", "0"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("__cmbTpvTm", "1581"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("TLTSID", "80B3B0043187103147A6A0A17B9EF771"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("dtCookie", "C74B98EA50CC90EF65913E3F5737B3B1|NMO+WN|1"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("dtPC", "143453468_465#click%20on%20%22Confirm%22"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("mbox", "session#1409541913733-591199#1409545314|check#true#1409543514"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("s_sess", "%20s_p49_start%3D1%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20orgTime%3D1409543456%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B%20s_ppv%3DChange%252520Shipping%252520Country%252C49%252C49%252C650%252C1366%252C650%252C1366%252C768%252C1%252CL%3B%20s_ppvl%3DChange%252520Shipping%252520Country%252C49%252C49%252C650%252C1366%252C650%252C1366%252C768%252C1%252CL%3B"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("dtLatC", "239|175|195.5|187|475.5|174|298|247.5|210|264|172"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("_br_mzs", "eyIxIjo5LCIyIjoxNDA5NTQxOTE3MTg5fQ"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("JSESSIONID", "501318DC317879C786F292889FC8E849"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("W2A", "3222077450.3930.0000"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("CChipCookie", "2097217546.61525.0000"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("TS4c652b", "9a9fa153d0e6a6af46d5cc37617b1cc036f3fea0668cb3575403ed1b"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("nm_akid", "820877FB8FA2C3D61BC5B994E2DA67BDD205664F725200003523B653E67D9F31"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("akid", "820877FB8FA2C3D61BC5B994E2DA67BDD205664F725200003523B653E67D9F31"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("akaau", "1409543758~id=e7bb81bd201420d2b50d3fb2b72a8149"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_m", "1"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_n", "1"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_mvtid", "338-1409542704363-21-8511"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_s", "b23492378.23492378"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_pv", "ds9XUk-c1d-J--jIjW8cG---%"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_ric", "b338.0.MC"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_uc", "1f96eeed-5929-43b6-f302-61520bcf63cc"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_utidc", "338.b"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("firstTimeUser", "here"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("_br_uid_1", "uid%3D5027964663387"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("ClrSSID", "1404445501993-9351"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("ClrOSSID", "1404445501993-9351"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("ClrSCD", "1404445501993"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("rr_rcs", "eF4NyrkNgDAMAMAGUWQXI7_CbMAa2EkkCjrC_KS-W8vzvXdlEQdSPARNkE0Z3MGNqIzJWaZvsYw8m80kjcCv3UGpJ6ApAaZR9BoSzj9znRUZ"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("ClrCSTO", "T"));
```

To get the price:

```
HtmlNode rawPrice = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='lineItem']/div[@class='lineItemData']/div[@class='lineItemInfo']/div[@class='adornmentPriceElement']/div[@class='price pos2']");
```

But it would either return EUR or my country's currency

**UPDATED**

**@rufanov**
I found the following using Fiddler,

```
POST http://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-mc/ajax.service HTTP/1.1
Host: www.neimanmarcus.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-mc/Aidan-Mattox-Strapless-Lace-Mermaid-Gown-Black/prod168090058/p.prod
Content-Length: 130
Cookie: TLTSID=C7F821A831EF1031A2E0E535646D82EE; TLTUID=C7F821A831EF1031A2E0E535646D82EE; JSESSIONID=1BB95B905E6D4AD6BCCCFACB4D53BD58; AGA=6300001:6500002~6300002:6500003~5400001:5400002~6300003:6500006~6100006:6300012~5400002:5400004~6100005:6300010; ABTEST_COOKIE=27806529983; ABTEST_COOKIE_CONFIRM=ef24b4e99ee78b5b0eefaa7ec3790d4d; W2A=3339517962.56665.0000; dtCookie=BF131B43CD539960F9AB29E318D8DED5|NMO+WN|1; CChipCookie=2113994762.61525.0000; TS4c652b=2cd866e0f296127b4a9981ef063eb0cb71e713ec01d4769f54053aa2286023f22d81158cec2531802d81158c60ac0ec565517ec261a4045b5442e2ae0541e448fa63d5093c25de05f6fd6a24219997378462f157219396cdbfb65f0b8524428a382d3cef4d8b7903fb8534b8fd4ed7b7a8ce5606f84d966dfb8534b84d8b7903fb8534b8fd4ed7b7a8ce5606aa4fdad3a28dfd269ea8724aa28dfd261f6ff00c0b55a5086151b9d8ae8f43c937aefe4a0e1b3aa94fcc411394598fba6edcc004808ba4f60fa38f01a7d63559; akaau=1409629669~id=11254370db65e4cd8de0b3f3be08f5b5; DYN_USER_ID=9277401074; DYN_USER_CONFIRM=57be096e15349ad19134b056ca2c67b9; WID=9277401074; dtPC=229039478_734#click%20on%20%22Confirm%22; NMCS=3E-u9d2bPVHVoGiYmKr_cW4_9Bl6VEdDl8GQBd1gQCwZg23UgR4vt7Q; s_sess=%20s_p49_start%3D1%3B%20s_sv_sid%3D503317300535%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20orgTime%3D1409629043%3B%20s_ppvl%3DProduct%252520Detail%252C28%252C28%252C382%252C1366%252C382%252C1366%252C768%252C1%252CL%3B%20s_ppv%3DChange%252520Shipping%252520Country%252C28%252C28%252C382%252C1366%252C382%252C1366%252C768%252C1%252CL%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B; s_pers=%20s_v17%3DNot%2520Assigned%7C1441165056833%3B%20s_v18%3DNot%2520Assigned%7C1441165056833%3B%20s_v20%3D0%7C1441165056833%3B%20s_v19%3D9277401074%7C1441165056833%3B%20gpv%3DChange%2520Shipping%2520Country%7C1409630858147%3B%20s_fid%3D4642B96D0F7EE894-3F6FAAD54AEFF39F%7C1472787474693%3B%20s_nr%3D1409629074728-Repeat%7C1441165074728%3B; firstTimeUser=here; dtLatC=590|402|583.5|1255|563|761.5|729.5|356|446|449.5|355.5; s_vi=[CS]v1|2A024AF8050121D2-6000010E80002DED[CE]; wlcme=true; nm_akid=A642CBA16FC32535AD74ACB8FE81010BCBB1260D35300000F0950454CF460777; akid=A642CBA16FC32535AD74ACB8FE81010BCBB1260D35300000F0950454CF460777; __cmbDomTm=0; _br_mzv=eyIxIjozLCIyIjoxNDA5NTg2Njg1ODMyLCIzIjoxNDA5NjI4NTU1MTEyLCI0IjoiaHR0cDovL3d3dy5uZWltYW5tYXJjdXMuY29tL2VuLW1jL0FpZGFuLU1hdHRveC1TdHJhcGxlc3MtTGFjZS1NZXJtYWlkLUdvd24tQmxhY2svcHJvZDE2ODA5MDA1OC9wLnByb2QiLCI1IjoiIn0; _br_uid_1=uid%3D9717749906180; _br_uid_2=uid%3D9717749906180%3Av%3D11.5%3Ats%3D1409586685839%3Ahc%3D14; __cmbU=ABJeb1-0cxpsi78ufqTp7XzYv5rnZCjoAXxvZIkj187WcacJnUqTHB-PMmNAssBaMJkvVofLLWybtkwRLEX399Z7n9xN14EZ_A; __cmbTpvTm=998; ClrSSID=1409586688735-9351; ClrOSSID=1409586688735-9351; ClrSCD=1409586688736; rr_m=1; rr_n=1; rr_mvtid=338-1409629035948-90-8510; rr_s=b23493817.23493817; rr_pv=dpiqdk-c1d-J--jIjW8cG---%; rr_ric=b338.0.MC; rr_uc=3ebbd78a-bc39-440f-772d-24520d18766c; rr_utidc=338.a; rr_rcs=eF4NzD0OgCAMQOHFOHCXmlL6xw28BmBIHNzE89vtveXb0_O990WlOGTGqhQpnC0OXDJua5zEkmdzAzatwF4bkLNCn0I4rCiypBXMSOEc_QdWMhRC; mbox=session#1409628542423-568873#1409630901|check#true#1409629101; _br_mzs=eyIxIjo0LCIyIjoxNDA5NjI4NTU1MTEyfQ; ClrCSTO=T
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

data=$b64$eyJDb250ZXh0Q2hvb3NlclJlcSI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiVVMiLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6IlVTRCIsImxhbmd1YWdlIjoiZW4ifX0$&timestamp=1409629074840
```

Should I pass the `data` variable to the request or should I do a separate AJAX function to get the values that I need?

Comment: Could you show what have you tried? Thanks.

Comment: @shifter can you tell me what you were using '__cmbU' cookie for?

Comment: @ap_snitch I’m not using it for anything, the domain we were scraping does, this was for my previous company though, i am not doing scraping anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like currently selected currency is stored on server and associated with you by session-id. When you change Country and Currency(for example "Monaco" and "US Dollars", client-side javascript generates json-string:

```
{"ContextChooserReq":{"country":"MC","currency":"USD","language":"en"}}
```

then encodes it using base64:

```
eyJDb250ZXh0Q2hvb3NlclJlcSI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiTUMiLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6IlVTRCIsImxhbmd1YWdlIjoiZW4ifX0=
```

And adds header that says to server "it's an base64-encoded-data":

```
$b64$eyJDb250ZXh0Q2hvb3NlclJlcSI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiTUMiLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6IlVTRCIsImxhbmd1YWdlIjoiZW4ifX0$
```

Then using AJAX client sends this string as form "data" field value to this Uri:

```
http://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-mc/ajax.service
```

Then browser reloads current page. Your session setting is now changed on server. That's it - country is now "Monaco" and currency is now "US Dollars".

You must check currency on current page. If it's not "USD", then you must do same thing as browser do - i.e. send POST-request to their ajax.service page with encoded base64-string with header as request body. It don't change, so if you want same currency always, you can send same string(as i written above). Then reload page and check currency again.

UPD:
Written working(but little ugly) class. I've used [CSQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery) instead of HAG(i just really don't like HAG):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using CsQuery;

namespace NMClient
{
    public struct Price
    {
        public string Currency;
        public decimal Value;
    }

    public class NMWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private const string TARGET_CURRENCY = "USD";
        private const string TARGET_CURRENCY_SWITCH_DATA = "$b64$eyJDb250ZXh0Q2hvb3NlclJlcSI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiTUMiLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6IlVTRCIsImxhbmd1YWdlIjoiZW4ifX0$";

        private CookieContainer _container;

        public NMWebClient()
        {
            _container = new CookieContainer();
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            var httpRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;

            if (httpRequest != null)
            {
                httpRequest.CookieContainer = this._container;
                return httpRequest;
            }
            else
            {
                return request;
            }
        }

        public static string GetTimestamp()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
        }

        public void SetCurrencyToUsDollars()
        {
            const string serviceUri = "http://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-mc/ajax.service";

            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values.Add("data", TARGET_CURRENCY_SWITCH_DATA);
            values.Add("timestamp", GetTimestamp());

            this.UploadValues(serviceUri, values);
        }

        public decimal GetUSDPriceValue(string uri)
        {
            var price = GetPrice(uri);

            if (price.Currency != TARGET_CURRENCY)
            {
                SetCurrencyToUsDollars();
                price = GetPrice(uri);

                if (price.Currency != TARGET_CURRENCY)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Can't switch price to " + TARGET_CURRENCY);
                }
            }

            return price.Value;
        }

        private Price GetPrice(string uri)
        {
            string price = GetPriceText(uri);
            int priceSeparator = price.IndexOf(' ');

            return new Price()
            {
                Currency = price.Substring(0, priceSeparator),
                Value = Convert.ToDecimal(price.Substring(priceSeparator + 1))
            };
        }

        private string GetPriceText(string uri)
        {
            var html = this.DownloadString(uri);
            var cq = CQ.Create(html);

            var priceElement = cq.Select("[itemprop=price]");

            return priceElement.Text().Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var client = new NMWebClient();

var uri = "http://www.neimanmarcus.com/en-mc/Aidan-Mattox-Strapless-Lace-Mermaid-Gown-Black/prod168090058/p.prod";
var price = client.GetUSDPriceValue(uri);   // 240
```

Try to not just copy, but to understand logic.

Comment: you saved my life!!! Thank you very much it worked now, just had to change a few things for my requirement! We should be close friends! hahaah!

Comment: there's a problem...TARGET_CURRENCY_SWITCH_DATA is different for every country, is there a way to get the string for each country?

Comment: There is two ways. First - you can add some JSON-serializer package to your project, generate JSON-string with any country/currency/language with same format as described above, then encode it to base64, add header, replace end-padding to dollar-symbol. Second, and more simpler way - you can replace TARGET_CURRENCY_SWITCH_DATA to some new argument of GetUSDPriceValue, then you can just catch some of this strings with servial different countries from Fiddler(i don't think that you really need all countries), and hardcore it in your code.